# Replace repeating characters with one with a regex

Tags: regex

I need a regex script to remove double repetition for these particular words..If these character occurs replace it with single.

```
/[\s.'-,{2,0}]
```

These are character that if they comes I need to replace it with single same character.

Comment: Regex can't quite do that alone. What programming language are you using the regex from, you might need a separate regex for each character, or something simpler depending on the language?

Comment: I am using this with javascript. adn php forms

Comment: Do you really mean the range from a single quote to a comma (i.e. `'()*+,`) or just the three characters `'-,`? And you only want `--`, `,,`, ... rather than things like `.,` and `.'`, right?

Comment: @mu is too short: Yes Exactly I want separetly like `--`,`,,`,`  `,`''`.

Comment: if first requirement is full fill than I restrict two type repetition. that is I will restrict `,.`,`.,`,`.-` o rnay other set.

Answer (score 18):

The [PCRE-compatible regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) to match this would be:

```perl
/([\s.',-])\1+/
```

If you're using Perl, you can *replace* it using the following expression:

```perl
s/([\s.',-])\1+/$1/g
```

If you're using PHP, then you would use this syntax:

```php
$out = preg_replace('/([\s.\',-])\1+/', '$1', $in);
```

### Explanation

- The `()` group matches the single character, in this case either a whitespace character (`\s`) or the punctuation characters (`. ' - ,`). It's good practice to put `-` at the end of the list inside `[]`.
- The `\1` means that the same thing it just matched in the parentheses occurs at least once more.
- In the replacement, the `$1` refers to the match in first set of parentheses.

Note: this is Perl-Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) syntax.

From the [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) man page:

> Matching repetitions
>
> The examples in the previous section display an annoying weakness.  We were only matching 3-letter words, or chunks of words of 4 letters or less.  We'd like to be able to match words or, more generally, strings of any length, without writing out tedious alternatives like `\w\w\w\w|\w\w\w|\w\w|\w`.
>
> This is exactly the problem the quantifier metacharacters `?`, `*`, `+`, and `{}` were created for. They allow us to delimit the number of repeats for a portion of a regexp we consider to be a match. Quantifiers are put immediately after the character, character class, or grouping that we want to specify. They have the following meanings:
>
> - `a?` means: match 'a' 1 or 0 times
> - `a*` means: match 'a' 0 or more times, i.e., any number of times
> - `a+` means: match 'a' 1 or more times, i.e., at least once
> - `a{n,m}` means: match at least "n" times, but not more than "m" times.
> - `a{n,}` means: match at least "n" or more times
> - `a{n}` means: match exactly "n" times

Comment: How will it replace it with single occurrence.

Comment: How can I do this with replace function like. 
    replace(/([\s.'-,])\1+ /ig, '')           
?

Comment: @Aditii: It's traditional here to at least mention the programming language when you are asking for language-specific help. I put the PHP syntax if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As others said it depends on you regex engine but a small example how you could do this:
`/([ _-,.])\1*/\1/g`

With sed:

```
$ echo "foo    , bar" | sed 's/\([ _-,.]\)\1*/\1/g'
foo , bar
$ echo "foo,. bar" | sed 's/\([ _-,.]\)\1*/\1/g'
foo,. bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript as mentioned in a commennt, and assuming (It's not too clear from your question) the characters you want to replace are space characters, `.`, `'`, `-`, and `,`:

```
var str = 'a  b....,,';
str = str.replace(/(\s){2}|(\.){2}|('){2}|(-){2}|(,){2}/g, '$1$2$3$4$5');
// Now str === 'a b..,'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do the following: given a set of characters, replace any multiple occurrence of each of them with a single character. Here's how I would do it in perl:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/\.{2,}/\./g; s/\-{2,}/\-/g; s/'{2,}/'/g" text.txt
```

If, for example, text.txt originally contains:

> Here is . and here are 2 .. that should become a single one. Here's
>   also a double -- that should become a single one. Finally here we have
>   three ''' which should be substituted with one '.

it is modified as follows:

> Here is . and here are 2 . that should become a single one. Here's
>   also a double - that should become a single one. Finally here we have
>   three ' which should be substituted with one '.

I simply use the same replacement regex for each character in in the set: for example

```
s/\.{2,}/\./g;
```

replaces 2 or more occurrences of a dot character with a single dot. I concatenate several of this expressions, one for each character of your original set.

There may be more compact ways of doing this, but, I think this is simple and it works :)

I hope it helps.

Comment: No need to escape the period or hyphen when they're used in the replacement section of the `s///`; it's not part of a regex at that point.