# Replace characters that repeats more than 20 times with 10 with a regex

Tags: python, regex, backreference

This is basically more complicated version of this question.

[Replace repeating characters with one with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172378/replace-repeating-characters-with-one-with-a-regex)

If there is a character that repeats more than 20 times, then replace with just ten repetition of that character.

That is, I want to replace 'adfajlkjl a sd=============================================== READFadfa' with 'adfajlkjl a sd========== READFadfa'

```
import re
string1 = 'adfajlkjl a sd=============================================== READFadfa'
re.sub(pattern1, r'\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1', string1)
```

Output:

```
'adfajlkjl a sd========== READFadfa'
```

The above is a brute force solution using the answer in the above link.
Is there another way not repeating the backreference \1 ten times?

Answer (score 2):

If your choice of programming language is Python, would you please try:

```
re.sub(r'(.)\1{19,}', lambda m: m.group(1) * 10, string1)
```

Result:

```
adfajlkjl a sd========== READFadfa
```