# Replacing a variable number of a repetitive character in a string

Tags: sql, pyspark, regexp-replace

I'm working out of Pyspark. We have tables that have various special characters that get replaced with underscores. However, in the event that multiple special characters appear one after the other we end up with multiple underscores in a row.

(i.e.  "This###is####annoying" is being modified to be "this___is____annoying" when it should be "this_is_annoying").

The problem is that a string could have any number of special characters in a row and, therefore, any number underscores in a row.

```
INSERT INTO tabC(something dumb) 
    SELECT 'This###is####annoying'
```

Desired output:

```
"This_is_annoying"
```

Is there a way to do a regexp_replace or something similar that will look for sequential underscores of any length and replace them with a single underscore?

Comment: Do any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172378/replace-repeating-characters-with-one-with-a-regex) help?

Comment: Or if Python is relevant to Pyspark (sorry, I'm not familiar), then maybe [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-replace-multiple-occurrence-of-character-by-single/)?

Comment: Where is this replace occurring? surely you'd want to fix this prior to it making it into the db? replacing repeated chars with a single one is a fairly simple regexp.

Comment: share the regex or code that replaces `#` to `_`

Comment: Pseudo Code: `reg_repl(pat="#+", rep="_", val=val)` ... the pattern is just `#+`